# Error when using a declared variable in SQL Query

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have payments per cnsmr_accnt_id going back several months.  I wish to see the total payments per month for the last 4 months.  Something like this:

```
Cnsmr_accnt_id   |   Wrkgrp_nm    |  Apr15_Tot  |  May15_Tot  |  Jun15_Tot  |  Jul15_Tot
12345            |Workgrp1        |  123424     |  1243255    |  232342     |  23232323
12347            |Workgrp4        |  123323     |  1244455    |  324342     |  232323
```

I am trying to use a Pivot to do this but keep getting an error when using the following code.  I suspect it's something to do with the variable @Dates scope.

@Dates is giving me the value Apr15,May15,Jun15,Jul15 which is right.

If I substitute this directly into the Select in the place of @Dates, the query works.  But the moment I use @Dates, it gives an error.  (Incorrect syntax near '@Dates'.)

I have also tried putting the whole "formula" used to Set @Dates into the select statement but this also gives an error.  (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left')

```
Declare @Dates as nvarchar(max); 
--Builds up a string of dates for the last 4 months. 
Set @Dates = left(datename(Month, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())), month(getdate())-3, 1)), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())), month(getdate())-3, 1)), 2) + ',' +
 left(datename(Month, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -2, getdate())), month(getdate())-2, 1)), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -2, getdate())), month(getdate())-2, 1)), 2)+ ',' +
 left(datename(Month, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -1, getdate())), month(getdate())-1, 1)), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -1, getdate())), month(getdate())-1, 1)), 2)+ ',' +
 left(datename(Month, getdate()), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, getdate()), 2);

 --Print @dates
--Example output = Apr15,May15,Jun15,Jul15

--Use a pivot to get the totals per cnsmr_accnt_id for the last 4 months. 
Select *
 from
(
Select  
    capj.cnsmr_accnt_id,
    wrkgrp_nm,
    max(UDEFINST_AMT) as Instlmnt,
    sum(cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_amnt) as Mnth_Tot, 
--Gives the Month & year (Eg Jul15)
    left(datename(Month, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 3) + right(datename(year, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 2) as Month_Yr
from 
    dbo.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl capj  
        inner join 
    UDEFGENERAL UG 
        on 
        capj.cnsmr_accnt_id = UG.cnsmr_accnt_id
        Inner join
    wrkgrp w 
        on
        capj.wrkgrp_id = w.wrkgrp_id
where
cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_stts_cd in (5)
and cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt between
--Go back to the 1st day 4 months back
datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())), month(getdate())-3, 1)
and 
getdate()
group by capj.cnsmr_accnt_id, 
left(datename(Month, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 3) + right(datename(year, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 2), 
 wrkgrp_nm) as Mnth_Tot_Tbl
 pivot 
 (
 sum(Mnth_Tot) 
 for 
 Month_Yr in (@Dates)) as Piv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the last 4 months worth of data I would suggest you approach this differently, rather than grouping by month and year, group by the number of months since this month. So rather than trying to dynamically pivot, you are just pivoting on static numbers (0, 1, 2, 3);

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  capj.cnsmr_accnt_id,
                    wrkgrp_nm,
                    Instlmnt = MAX(udefinst_amt),
                    Mnth_Tot = SUM(cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_amnt), 
                    MonthsSinceToday = DATEDIFF(MONTH, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt, GETDATE())
            FROM    dbo.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl AS capj  
                    INNER JOIN Udefgeneral AS ug
                        ON capj.cnsmr_accnt_id = ug.cnsmr_accnt_id
                    INNER JOIN wrkgrp AS w 
                        ON capj.wrkgrp_id = w.wrkgrp_id
            WHERE   cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_stts_cd IN (5)
            AND     cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000401', GETDATE()), '19000101')
            AND     cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt < GETDATE()
            GROUP BY cnsmr_accnt_id, wrkgrp_nm, DATEDIFF(MONTH, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt, GETDATE())
        ) AS d
        PIVOT 
        (   SUM(Mnth_Tot)
            FOR MonthsSinceToday IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
        ) AS pvt;
```

The downside of this approach is that your dates won't be column headers, but the upside is you don't need to use dynamic sql, and column names should be fairly easily handled by your presentation layer anyway.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, the scales have fallen from my eyes!  Appreciate the assistance tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to use dynamic sql or use the following instead of Month_Yr in (@Dates)

```
','+@Dates+',' like '%,'+Month_Yr+',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 First Convert second part into dynamic string  and create string query after execute your Query
EXEC('Select *
 from
(
Select  
    capj.cnsmr_accnt_id,
    wrkgrp_nm,
    max(UDEFINST_AMT) as Instlmnt,
    sum(cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_amnt) as Mnth_Tot, 
--Gives the Month & year (Eg Jul15)
    left(datename(Month, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 3) + right(datename(year, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 2) as Month_Yr
from 
    dbo.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl capj  
        inner join 
    UDEFGENERAL UG 
        on 
        capj.cnsmr_accnt_id = UG.cnsmr_accnt_id
        Inner join
    wrkgrp w 
        on
        capj.wrkgrp_id = w.wrkgrp_id
where
cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_stts_cd in (5)
and cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt between
--Go back to the 1st day 4 months back
datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())), month(getdate())-3, 1)
and 
getdate()
group by capj.cnsmr_accnt_id, 
left(datename(Month, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 3) + right(datename(year, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 2), 
 wrkgrp_nm) as Mnth_Tot_Tbl
 pivot 
 (
 sum(Mnth_Tot) 
 for 
 Month_Yr in (' + @Dates + ')) as Piv')
```

Comment: Wow, okay that solution works too.  Thank you very much!  The one nice thing about doing it this way is that the month names come through in the column headings which could be a pro or con depending on what you plan on doing next!

Answer (score 0):

So we have 2 answers above that work.  Thank you to GarethD and Pradip.

Just to conclude, I tested Pradip's solution as follows:

```
Declare @Dates as nvarchar(max); 
--Builds up a string of dates for the last 4 months. 
Set @Dates = left(datename(Month, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())), month(getdate())-3, 1)), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())), month(getdate())-3, 1)), 2) + ',' +
 left(datename(Month, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -2, getdate())), month(getdate())-2, 1)), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -2, getdate())), month(getdate())-2, 1)), 2)+ ',' +
 left(datename(Month, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -1, getdate())), month(getdate())-1, 1)), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -1, getdate())), month(getdate())-1, 1)), 2)+ ',' +
 left(datename(Month, getdate()), 3) + 
 right(datename(year, getdate()), 2);


EXEC('Select *
 from
(
Select  
    capj.cnsmr_accnt_id,
    wrkgrp_nm,
    max(UDEFINST_AMT) as Instlmnt,
    sum(cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_amnt) as Mnth_Tot, 
--Gives the Month & year (Eg Jul15)
    left(datename(Month, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 3) + right(datename(year, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 2) as Month_Yr
from 
    dbo.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl capj  
        inner join 
    UDEFGENERAL UG 
        on 
        capj.cnsmr_accnt_id = UG.cnsmr_accnt_id
        Inner join
    wrkgrp w 
        on
        capj.wrkgrp_id = w.wrkgrp_id
where
cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_stts_cd in (5)
and cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt between
--Go back to the 1st day 4 months back
datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())), month(getdate())-3, 1)
and 
getdate()
group by capj.cnsmr_accnt_id, 
left(datename(Month, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 3) + right(datename(year, cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt), 2), 
 wrkgrp_nm) as Mnth_Tot_Tbl
 pivot 
 (
 sum(Mnth_Tot) 
 for 
 Month_Yr in (' + @Dates + ')) as Piv')
```